# TokenMismatchException in Laravel 5.0

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a `form` inside a `div`.

```
<div class="form-container col-sm-12 container-fluid">
<meta content="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
<form class="form" id="register_form" method="POST" novalidate>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" id="token"> -->
    <div class="form-group" id="error_msg"></div>
    <div class="form-group name">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" role="group" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>                  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group email"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>      
    </div>
    <div class="form-group contact_no">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="contact_no" placeholder="Contact No" name="contact_no" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group select_level">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="level_interested" id="level_interested" required>
            <option class="form-control" selected disabled value="">Level Interested</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="bachelor">Bachelor</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="masters">Masters</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="phd">Phd</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="nursing">Nursing</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group select_country">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="country_interested" id="country_interested" required>
            <option class="form-control" selected disabled value="">Country Interested</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="usa">U.S.A</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="australia">Australia</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="canada">Canada</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="india">India</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="new_zealand">New Zealand</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When the `form` is submitted, validation is carried on. After successful validation, I use `Ajax` to send input data and display alert message in response.

```
form.submit(function() {
        if(validateName() & validateEmail() & validateContact_No() & validateLevel() & validateCountry()) {

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type : 'post',

            url: "{{ route('save_registry') }}",

            data: {
                'name' : name.val(),
                'email' : email.val(),
                'contact_no' : contact_no.val(),
                'level_interested' : level_interested.val(),
                'country_interested' : country_interested.val(),
            },

            success : function(data) {

                    alert(data);

            }
        });
            return true;
        } else {
            $('#error_msg').text("Please Enter Details Correctly").show().addClass('text-danger').addClass('text-center');
            return false;
        }
```

This is my `function` in a `Controller` to handle the request.

```
public function save_registry(Request $request)
{


    $new_registry = new Register();

    $email = Register::where('email','=',$request->email)->exists();
    if($email==true)
    {
        return 'Email already exists';
    }
    else{
        $new_registry -> name = $request -> name;
        $new_registry -> email = $request -> email;
        $new_registry -> contact_no = $request -> contact_no;
        $new_registry -> level_interested = $request -> level_interested;
        $new_registry -> country_interested = $request -> country_interested;
        $new_registry->save();
        return 'Registered Successfully';
    }
}
```

After I submit the `form`, alert is popped. And after I close the alert, I get `TokenMismatchException` error. I get this error only when the `form's method` is `POST` not in `GET`. So is there any solution to not to get the error when the `method` is `POST`?

Comment: Reading the docs have you tried `X-CSRF-TOKEN` instead of `X-CSRF-Token` not sure if the header is case sensitive

Comment: Header is not case sensitive. I only get 'TokenMismatchException' after the `form` is successfully submitted. `Form` datas are also successfully inserted in the database. `Alert` with the message form `controller's function`  also pops up. But after I close the `alert`, I get `TokenMismatchException`. If `token` was mismatched I would have get the error right after I hit the `submit`, not after closing the `alert`.

Comment: sounds like you need to prevent the original form from submitting then, add callback variable e to submit function and use `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel looks for an attribute called `_token` when you submit a form via `POST`. I see you already have this in a `<meta>` tag, so you have two methods to get this when you `POST` your form.

First, you can create a new `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>` element somewhere in your `<form>`, and make sure that is passed via your ajax when the method is `POST`:

```
data: {
    '_token' : _token.val(),
    'name' : name.val(),
    'email' : email.val(),
    'contact_no' : contact_no.val(),
    'level_interested' : level_interested.val(),
    'country_interested' : country_interested.val(),
},
```

Alternatively, since you already have the conent in a `<meta>` tag, you can just include it in your ajax like so:

```
data: {
    '_token' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
    'name' : name.val(),
    'email' : email.val(),
    'contact_no' : contact_no.val(),
    'level_interested' : level_interested.val(),
    'country_interested' : country_interested.val(),
},
```

Regardless of how you do it, just make sure to have that `_token` attribute in your `POST` data, and it should work for you. Hope that helps!